# Why this vehicle can't turning left in SUMO Traffic Simulation?

Tags: simulation, traffic, sumo, traffic-simulation

I can manipulate SUMO Traffic Simulation with TCP/IP. I am always feed SUMO with data. But traffic can't move because some vehicle do not turn. I added picture below;

[Picture of trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jhil.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think understand problem. Because front car want U-turn and he can't do this and wait and lock the all traffic.